# How to return a value into koa generator?

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback, generator, koa

I've got something like this:

```
var app = koa;

var run = function (generator){
  var it = generator(go);
  function go(err, res) {
    it.next(res);
  }
  go();      
}


app.use(function *() {
  run(function *(callback) {
     var result = yield asyncFunc(params, callback);
  });
  //I want to get value of result here;
});
```

So how to get this value using Koa conception?

Comment: What is this `run` thingy? Why write your own instead of using `co`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is solution I found

```
var app = koa;

var foo = function(params) {
    return function(callback) {
        asyncFunc(params, function(err, result){
            if (err) callback(err);
            callback(null, result);
        });
    }
}

app.use(function *() {
  var result;
  try {
      result = yield foo(params);
  } catch {
      result = null;
  }
  console.log(result);
});
```

Comment: You wrapped it in a function that creates a thunk (i.e. returns a function that takes one argument: the callback), and this works because `co` can yield thunks. But I recommend wrapping it in a Promise instead of a thunk since it's the more general solution rather than a rather dated co-specific hack. The other answer to your question shows how.

Answer (score 0):

To get the value of your function, just wrap it in a Promise

```
app.use(function *(){
 var promise = new Promise (function(resolve, reject){
   asyncFunc(params, function(err, res){
      if(err){reject(err)}
      else{resolve(res)}
   }
 }

 /*Added koa error handling example also*/
 try {
   var result = yield Promise
   // do what you want with result
 }
 catch{
   this.status = 500 // or 404, etc, whatever is appropriate
   /* the Koa docs have examples and go more in depth on error handling*/     
 }
}
```

Also you don't have to run (middleware) generators yourself, you just yield them also.  That's what Koa's middleware chaining is all about